# Add cell data to new column at the end of each row in excel?

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

I have a spreadsheet and I need to combine the information in three cells and add the combined information to a new cell on the same row. For example, I have columns A through M and rows 1 through 10. I need to add the information in column C, D, and E of each row and add that information to the end of each row, which would be column N.

I can use a variation of `=C2&" "&D2&" "&E2` and manually add that to a new column (N) but I have about 12,000 rows so that might take quite some time :)

Is there a specific expression (correct wording?) or formula I can use to automate this process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any problem with using `=C2&" "&D2&" "&E2` in the `N2` cell.  The beauty of Excel is that once you have written the formula once, you can simply drag it down to the cells below it.  As you drag, Excel will automatically reference the next row. `N3` would be filled with `=C3&" "&D3&" "&E3`, `N4` would be filled with `=C4&" "&D4&" "&E4`, etc.

To drag a formula down, select the `N2` cell where the formula is written.  At the bottom-right corner of the border of that cell, grab the square and drag down.  You can also double-click that square to fill down to the end of your data (it would do all 12,000 rows in two clicks).

Comment: "once you have written the formula once, you can simply drag it down to the cells below it. As you drag, Excel will automatically reference the next row" Yep, that's it, thanks!